# Microsoft Graph API: UnknownError when i am trying to get a call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to get the subject (ex. Maths 1) of an online TEAMS meeting via Microsoft Graph API.

When i send a request to **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/8f4477a7-f5b2-40ed-a165-95519825c9cg** in the response there is no value for the subject of the meeting.

So my next move is to send a request to **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/8f4477a7-f5b2-40ed-a165-95519825c9cg** because the Graph API documentation has the property *'subject'* in the response. When i send this request i get this response:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2021-02-10T12:32:19",
        "request-id": "9a81a114-8a58-457b-929v-390bda79669g",
        "client-request-id": "9a81a114-8a58-457b-929a-490bda79669g"
    }
}
```

}

with a response status code : **500 Interval Server Error** from the Graph API.

I have tried this request with different meeting ids but the result is the same.

My API permissions are these:
[API Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHhgF.png)

I would appreciate it if I had a solution to my problem or some other way to find the subject of the meeting.

Comment: Maybe you're not using an authorization with you token in the request header.
You can follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) to get further help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting that error is because you are querying the teams meeting as a resource of type 'call' instead of 'event'.

Please use GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid) |userPrincipalName}/events/{id} using Calendars.Read Application permission when querying as an application or GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events/%7Bid%7D) with the Calendars.Read delegated permissions when querying as a signed-in user.
For further reference, have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @Pedro krns, please let us know if your issue has been resolved